# MySql upsert and auto-increment causes gaps

Tags: mysql, upsert

I've got a MySql table with an auto-increment primary key, and it seems that all of the various upsert methods (INSERT IGNORE and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) suffer from the, uh, feature that the auto-increment field increments, even if a row is updated and not inserted.  This means that gaps are introduced into the table, which I find undesirable.

So the question is: is there any way to upsert records in a table with an auto-increment field *without* auto-incrementing that field, if the upsert in fact merely updates the row.  To my mind, this is the way upsert should behave, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I find your concern about these gaps a way more undesirable. One sholdn't be concerned of auto_oncrement numbers at all. You are probably misunderstood it's concept.

Comment: I understand that the actual values are meaningless, but if you waste too many of them, you can run out of space and need to go to a bigger data type, and then all of the rows will take up that much more space.  Also, I find the gaps inelegant, although I suppose that's not the biggest deal.

Comment: `MySQL` supports `SERIAL` type which is an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`. `BIGINT` can hold values up to `18,446,744,073,709,551,615`. I'm leaving a nice metaphorical comparison (like, to the age of the universe etc.) as an exercise for the reader. And it's only `8` bytes, too.

Comment: Fair enough, although using the extra 4 bytes seems wasteful, but I guess it's not a big deal in most applications.

Comment: I wrote up an innodb gap answer [Over Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363271)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "problem" is only in `InnoDB`.

It is by design, and intended to improve concurrency: another thread can use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` without having to wait for the results of an `UPSERT` operation.

From the [**docs**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html):

> After a server startup, for the first insert into a table `t`, `InnoDB` executes the equivalent of this statement:
>
> ```
> SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM t FOR UPDATE;
> ```
>
> **…**
>
> `InnoDB` initializes but does not increment the value and stores it for use by later inserts
>
> **…**
>
> When accessing the auto-increment counter, `InnoDB` uses a special table-level `AUTO-INC` lock that it keeps to the end of the current `SQL` statement, not to the end of the transaction. The special lock release strategy was introduced to improve concurrency for inserts into a table containing an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. Nevertheless, two transactions cannot have the `AUTO-INC` lock on the same table simultaneously, which can have a performance impact if the `AUTO-INC` lock is held for a long time. That might be the case for a statement such as `INSERT INTO t1 ... SELECT ... FROM t2` that inserts all rows from one table into another.

`MyISAM` does not exhibit this behavior, since it's `AUTO_INCREMENT` algorithm is implemented differently (due to its limited ability to support concurrent `DML`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information about why this behavior is as intended.  I'll accept the answer, but I'd still like to know if there's any high-performance way to accomplish upsert without gaps.

Comment: @Joshua: you could create a single-field, single-record "sequence" table and update it in a trigger. However, that would severely hurt the concurrency of your table.

Comment: @Quassnoi : I'm running MyISAM and got the same problem

Comment: @hornetbzz: please post it as another question.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Just to say I do not believe this problem is not strictly Innodb related, as I solved my problem just adding a unique constraint on the key field (unlinking the AI field). As I guess you're french, you'll be able to see what/how [here](http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1052735/bases-donnees/mysql/mysql-5-0-upsert/#post5847149)

Comment: @hornetbzz: I'm Russian, but with little Google translating I can see that the problem you posted on that forum has little to do with this. A key violation on `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will increment the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column on `InnoDB` but not on `MyISAM`. In your original query, there were no key violation at all.