# How to Permanently Delete Table Data

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I have table that have 4 fields.
i.e.
**1.** id : ***Primary key***, ***Auto Increment*** ,
**2.** name,
**3.** salary,
**4.** designation.

when I add data id increments automatically.
Suppose when I remove or delete row that have `id = 15` i.e. last record and after that if I add new record then id starts from `16`.
So that is my problem, **when I remove record It should be permanently removed**.
and id starts from `15` again.

Any suggestion for it ?

Comment: Don't `auto increment` and use `max(id)+1`

Comment: If I ll truncate table then existing data remain or deleted ?

Comment: Never, ever, reuse identifiers. They identify a single record. Introduce an additional column that represents the order of records. Eventually they can be continuous.

Comment: @Caramiriel - sorry I exactly don't understand what you mean ?? Will You explain me ?

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ - At the moment the record is inserted, the record gets an identifier. Once this record is deleted and reinserted with the same identifier, the system thinks its the same record. At a later point there is no possibility to know if it was actually the same record or not (which may get you into trouble, such as foreign keys that point to the wrong record, etc.).

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ use : `delete from table_name`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi - I have used that to remove/delete row but I permanently want to remove that row so when I add new record it start from that one again.

Comment: @Caramiriel - okay sir I have got it but any suggestion for my problem ? Or I ll have to solve it by other way...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql upsert and auto-increment causes gaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679611/mysql-upsert-and-auto-increment-causes-gaps)

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ: I would suggest adding an additional column that represents the order that you've intended. But I'm awaiting any other answers that may be better.

Comment: @Caramiriel - Okay sir, I ll also wait sometime for to get answer otherwise I ll try to implement your idea or if any better. Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the `Primary Key` on a table on RDBMS is to uniquely identify a record **FOREVER**. Even if you delete this record, its id "remains there" forever. The world needs to know that the record with id e.g. `15`, existed once, but does not exist anymore. **You should not be reusing primary keys that have been deleted**. It is a wrong business and technical approach. You will get into much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If you have used sequence for auto increment for the 'id' and  you delete a record with id = 15 then the sequence will get the next value i.e 16 as it has already picked the value 15 as it is independent of whether the id exists in the table or not. Hope it helps you.